# Intel UHD 620 drivers

Tags: 20.04, intel-graphics, ubuntu-drivers

How can i download Intel UHD620 drivers for Ubuntu 20.04 on my Thinkpad L390. I just started using Linux and not aware where to find the drivers.

Comment: there is no need to install the drivers, they are already included..

Answer (score 0):

look at these

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005520/graphics.html

Linux users

Most Linux-based* distributions include Intel® Graphics Drivers. These drivers are provided and maintained by the Linux* distribution vendors. Contact your operating system vendor (OSV) and use their distribution for driver access and support.

Comment: Yup, this isn't Windows where you have to pay extreme attention to video drivers.